# How to customize the chaincode container name during installation (using chaincode lifecycle install)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy the chaincode to a fabric peer using "peer lifecycle install".
It works perfectly. System can build and create the chaincode container as expected.
The images are automatically created after installing chaincode with prefix "dev-peer0.xxx"
I'd like to set the custom name like : pro-peer0.xxx.. instead of default (dev-peer0).

Can you help to advise?
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58xlA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a configurable option of a peer to change the network id see https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/8576508403cd6e3cbb5f7a2ff05dfae123de227b/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L19, you can change the core.yaml file in the peer.
If you are using docker-compose then you can change it using an env var of
`CORE_PEER_NETWORKID`